# How to pass the arguments to a click function of a button through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

On document ready I have registered for a click event for a button. Now from the knockout JS click event I want to pass few extra parameters the JavaScript click event. How do I achieve this?

I  am using knockout binding for one of the button; as below:

```
<input id="defaultButton" value="Submit" type="button" data-bind="click: defaultButton.defaultbuttonClick" />.
```

Now I have a click event attached to the button as below:

```
$("#defaultButton").click(mycode);
```

and the function:

```
function mycode(val, val1, val3, val4) {
    debugger;
    var instancexml = val.name;
    alert("inside = " + val);
 }
```

Now from the knockout event I would like to pass `Val1`, `Val2` and `Val3` based on some logic.

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario more detail.The details are not sufficient to answer.

Comment: I am using knockout binding for one of the button. as below.<input id="defaultButton" value="Submit" type="button" data-bind="click: defaultButton.defaultbuttonClick" />. Now I have a click event attached to the button as below $("#defaultButton").click(mycode); and the function function mycode(val, val1, val3, val4)
                {
                    debugger;
                    var instancexml = val.name;
                    alert("inside = " + val);
                }. Now from the knockout event I would like to pass Val1, Val2 and Val3 based on some logic.

Comment: Anyone has any update on this.

Comment: @Anand I am using knockout binding for one of the button. as below.'<input id="defaultButton" value="Submit" type="button" data-bind="click: defaultButton.defaultbuttonClick" />'. Now I have a click event attached to the button as below '$("#defaultButton").click(mycode);' and the function 'function mycode(val, val1, val3, val4) { debugger; var instancexml = val.name; alert("inside = " + val); }'. Now from the knockout event I would like to pass Val1, Val2 and Val3 based on some logic